# I found a net connection error while using localhost in jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I wrote this program to connect with my database which is on the same computer but i found a net connection error each time. com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Demo {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {   
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db","username","pwd");   
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            String str="SHOW TABLES";
            ResultSet resultSet=stmt.executeQuery(str);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

My Stacktrace is:-

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:8)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:8)
```

Comment: Check your database configuration. It could be problems with firewall or with wrong port.

Comment: Is your mysql service running?

Comment: Is your database server up and listening on port `3306` ?

Answer (score 0):

This error was mainly due to Mysql server not reachable or not running. Check with below points:

```
1. Check your DB Connection whether MYSQL is up and running. 
2. Check if you are able to connect from command prompt
3. Restart the mysql server and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname","username","password");
```

If this is not sorted out go to where you installed Mysql and open MySQL Notifier and check server is running or not if not start it and then try executing your program.